# A question about Gauss Bonnet theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

If $S$ is a surface which is the complement of finitely many points in a compact surface, and the metric in $S$ is complete, then is Gauss-Bonnet theorem still valid for $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.

http://www.ams.org/proc/1982-086-01/S0002-9939-1982-0663893-8/S0002-9939-1982-0663893-8.pdf

Answer (score 2):

No.

Take the sphere $S^2$ and remove one point, giving you a surface $S$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  So we can equip $S$ with a metric making it isometric to $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is certainly complete.  $\mathbb{R}^2$ has zero curvature but its Euler characteristic is $1$, so
$$ 0 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} K dVol \ne \chi(\mathbb{R}^2) = 1.$$

Comment: Yes, I think I should add one more condition, $S$ has finite area, then it will be true, as shown by Max

Comment: @hao: What is an example of a complete, connected, noncompact Riemannian manifold of finite area?  I'm having trouble thinking of one.

Comment: If a small disk in the sphere is replaced by a 'spike' extending indefinitely we can get such a surface. I.e., something like half of the [Tractricoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere), which has finite area. This is the image invoked by the short paper that Max linked to.

Comment: @yasmar: Thanks.  I was trying to think of something like that, but I kept coming up with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_Horn instead.

Answer (score -1):

No.

If you remove a finite set of points from a compact surface, it will no longer be complete. If you change the metric so that you do have a complete surface, you cannot apply the Gauss Bonnet theorem anyway, because the surface isn't compact.

Comment: You can't *apply* the Gauss-Bonnet theorem, but its conclusion could still hold.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Yes, as the nice two page paper that Max linked to shows. I was clearly too quick to blow the question off.